# uneven matrix transformation in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a sample data that has NAs in each of the column and only one value. I want to condense the table by removing all NAs but keeping only the value in a single row.
sample input:
[image]
sample input code:

```
   structure(list(key = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L), col1 = c("val1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "val44", "val3", "val4", 
NA, NA), col2 = c(NA, "val2", NA, NA, NA, NA, "val7", "val13", 
"val19", "val25", NA), col3 = c(NA, NA, "val3", NA, NA, NA, "val8", 
"val14", "val20", NA, NA), col4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "val4", NA, NA, 
"val9", "val15", "val21", NA, NA), col5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "val5", 
NA, "val10", "val16", "val22", NA, "val26"), col6 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "val6", "val11", "val17", "val23", NA, NA), col.7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "val12", "val18", "val24", NA, NA), col8 = c("same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value"
), col9 = c("same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

sample output :
[image]

output code:

```
structure(list(key = 1:5, col1 = c("val1", "val44", "val3", "val4", 
NA), col2 = c("val2", "val7", "val13", "val19", "val25"), col3 = c("val3", 
"val8", "val14", "val20", "val26"), col4 = c("val4", "val9", 
"val15", "val21", NA), col5 = c("val5", "val10", "val16", "val22", 
NA), col6 = c("val6", "val11", "val17", "val23", NA), col.7 = c(NA, 
"val12", "val18", "val24", NA), col8 = c("same_value", "same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value", "same_value"), col9 = c("same_value", 
"same_value", "same_value", "same_value", "same_value")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem with your input data

Comment: resolved the error now

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, based on `tidyr::fill`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  fill(2:8, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>     key col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col.7 col8       col9      
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1     1 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  <NA>  same_value same_value
#> 2     2 val44 val7  val8  val9  val10 val11 val12 same_value same_value
#> 3     3 val3  val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18 same_value same_value
#> 4     4 val4  val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24 same_value same_value
#> 5     5 <NA>  val25 <NA>  <NA>  val26 <NA>  <NA>  same_value same_value
```

Comment: Im curious about the fill operator, can we use this if the database is huge with thousands of records? what does 2:8 mean here

Comment: I believe that function `fill` will work in much larger datasets, but I have not test it in huge datasets . `2:8` means columns with indexes from 2 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `summarize` call across all columns and take the maximum value among each group.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ max(.x, na.rm = T)))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#>     key col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col.7 col8       col9      
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1     1 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  <NA>  same_value same_value
#> 2     2 val44 val7  val8  val9  val10 val11 val12 same_value same_value
#> 3     3 val3  val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18 same_value same_value
#> 4     4 val4  val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24 same_value same_value
#> 5     5 <NA>  val25 <NA>  <NA>  val26 <NA>  <NA>  same_value same_value
```

And a slightly longer version without the warning messages:

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.x)), NA, max(.x, na.rm = T))))
```

---

On the side, here's a base R option:

```r
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$key), function(a) sapply(a, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and calling your data.frame `df`. Not all that different from the other answers.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, min, na.rm=TRUE), keyby=.(key)]
##    key  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7       col8       col9
## 1:   1  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  <NA> same_value same_value
## 2:   2 val44  val7  val8  val9 val10 val11 val12 same_value same_value
## 3:   3  val3 val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18 same_value same_value
## 4:   4  val4 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24 same_value same_value
## 5:   5  <NA> val25  <NA>  <NA> val26  <NA>  <NA> same_value same_value
```

If you want to apply this to only some of the columns,

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, min, na.rm=TRUE), keyby=.(key), .SDcols=paste0('col', 1:7)]
##    key  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
## 1:   1  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  <NA>
## 2:   2 val44  val7  val8  val9 val10 val11 val12
## 3:   3  val3 val13 val14 val15 val16 val17 val18
## 4:   4  val4 val19 val20 val21 val22 val23 val24
## 5:   5  <NA> val25  <NA>  <NA> val26  <NA>  <NA>
```